# передача данных из view в представление

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, json, django

Как передать JSON объект в JS код в представление Django? В данном случае как передать `responseData` в массив `points`?

**view:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.http import JsonResponse
from .models import Station

# Create your views here.
class List(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'station_list.html'

    def get(self, request):
        all_stations = Station.objects.all()
        ctx = {
            'all_stations': all_stations,
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, ctx)


def index(request):
    responseData = {
        'point': [22, 44]}
    return render(request, "station_list.html", context={'responseData': responseData})
```

**Представление:**

```
    <script>
    points = []; //массив в который надо поместить responseData
    points.push("{{point}}");
    </script>
</head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Станции и обсерватории</h1>
<div id="viewDiv"></div>
{% block content %}
<h1>{{ point }}</h1>
<table border='1' cellpadding="5px">
    <tr style='background: black; color: white;'>
        <td>Id</td>
        <td>Код</td>
        <td>Имя</td>
        <td>Широта</td>
        <td>Долгота</td>
        <td>Тип</td>
        <td>Ссылка</td>
    </tr>
    {% for station in all_stations %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{station.Pk}}</td>
        <td>{{station.sitecode}}</td>
        <td>{{station.namestation}}</td>
        <td>{{station.latitude}}</td>
        <td>{{station.longitude}}</td>
        <td>{{station.type}}</td>
        <td><a href={{station.link}}>{{station.link}}</a></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Использовать вместо JsonResponse функцию render. И в отрендеренный шаблон  передать в контексте ваш json.

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров, изменил view и представление. Та же проблема в массив points ничего не добавилось.

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров правильно ли я его принимаю в представлении, может надо как-то по другому принимать данные в представлении?

Comment: попробуйте вместо return render(request, "station_list.html", responseData) написать return render(request, "station_list.html", context = {'responseData': responseData }). И в шаблоне соответственно вызывать {{responseData}}.

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров изменил  view и представление как вы сказали, ничего не поменялось

Comment: Ну а что-то вообще в шаблон-то передается? Скажем, если написать render(request, "station_list.html", context = {'some_text': 'some_text' }), а в шаблоне вызвать {{some_text}} - это работает?

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров странно, но ничего не выводится. Однако все данные которые я получаю из моделей  на странице отображаются. Добавил весь код из views и часть кода из представления, скрипт js в представлении добавил не полностью.

Comment: Насколько я понял вы пытаетесь использовать 2 view одновременно. Так не получится. Нужно сформировать ваш json в функции get вашей вьюхи List, и там записать ее в контекст.  ctx = { 'all_stations': all_stations, 'responseData': responseData }.

Comment: Ну вы, конечно, можете определить где-то функцию, которая будет этот json формировать и во вьюхе просто получать результат ее работы. Но общий принцип такой. Возможно я не совсем понимаю вашу ситуацию, но из того, что видно в вопросе наверное так. И еще там head 2 раза закрыт в примере.

Comment: Написал в ответ пример

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86636/discussion-between---and--).

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров давайте

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Весь контекст нужно сформировать в одной вьюхе. А потом передать его в шаблон Например:

```
def get_json():
    #Какие-то действия
    responseData = {} #каким-то образом формируется json
    return responseData

class List(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'station_list.html'


    def get(self, request):
        all_stations = Station.objects.all()
        responseData = get_json()
        ctx = {
            'all_stations': all_stations, 'responseData': responseData
        }

        return render(request, self.template_name, ctx)
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, всё работает.